# iOS UIView/UIScrollView overlay with zoom capability

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, overlay

I have a UIView/UIScrollView with non rectangular sections, let's call them room plans.
The UIView/UIScrollView should be zoomable. 
When the user clicks to a non rectangular region/room, I should be able to detect which region was clicked and let's say open up the detailed floorplan of that particular room.
The problem is that
1. when I zoom in and out, the 'button' size must change.
2. the button is not rectangular.

see an example of what I am trying to implement in iOS.
http://www.occc.net/ifp/

Any ideas of how to approach this problem are welcome.

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do a similar thing there. What i did was use a UIImageView within a UIScrollView and load the image in the UIImageView.

I did this in  my viewDidLoad :

```
 scrollMap.minimumZoomScale=1;
 scrollMap.maximumZoomScale=2.0;
 scrollMap.delegate=self;
```

Then added this function :

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imgMap;
}
```

This made the image inside the scrollview zoomable with the aspect ratio of the scrollview. It worked for me. You can try, this might work for you too.

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up going this way and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton), i found on github and i have used in more than three apps.

It is very easy to implement you should try this.....

Comment: thanks. yes, I have been using OBShapedButton in the past, but this won't help me if the image is zoomed out I guess. Unless I adjust the button size together with the view.

Comment: for zooming functionality of your project dont zoom image.Try zooming entire OBShapedButton. this may solve your problem